# Submitting using check box

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

Hi I have following check box and a button. I want to check the box and than call a function when the button is clicked using jquery.

```
        <form id="rForm" >
          <table id="testing" class=""    border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <td> <label class="" for="_person" >Person</label></td>
               <td> <input type="checkbox" class="_person" id="rov" name="person"/></td>
                 <td><input type="button" id="personList" class=""  value="Search" /></td>
              </tr>
          </table>
        </form>


        $(document).ready(function () {
              $("#vendorList").click(function () {

                  if ($("input:checkbox:checked").val() = "vendor") {
                      fnloadlist();
                  }
              });                 
          });
```

When I run using firebug. It gives error "ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side" at if statement. 
I tried few different things but nothing seem to work. 
Please help as I am new to jquery. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `===` instead of `=` for comparison
- Your checkbox doesn't have value attribute
- There is no element with ID of `vendorList` in your markup
- You can select the checkbox by ID (since it has one) and check whether it's checked or not using `.prop()` method:

  ```
  if ( $('#rollUPForm_vendor').prop('checked') ) {
      //                      |                                 
      //                      => returns true/false
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<form id="rollUpForm" >
  <table id="testing" class=""    border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <td> <label class="" for="_person" >Person</label></td>
       <td> <input type="checkbox" class="_person" id="rollUPForm_vendor" value="person" name="person"/></td>
         <td><input type="button" id="personList" class=""  value="Search" /></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
       $(function() {
         $(document).ready(function () {
            function fnloadlist () {
                alert('Yes');
            }
              $("#personList").click(function () {              
                  if ($("input:checkbox:checked").val() == "person") {
                      fnloadlist();
                  }
              });                 
          });   


        });
    </script>
```